# Did the Chofetz Chaim check his esrogim with a magnifying glass?

Tags: sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

[Many people](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95585/esrog-only-passul-when-under-magnifying-glass) hold that an esrog [can be checked with the naked eye](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Etrog#cite_note-6), but in practice many people use a magnifying glass.

Did the saintly [Chofetz Chaim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisrael_Meir_Kagan) zy”a use a magnifying glass when inspecting his own esrog for succos?

Comment: This question is clearly about Judaism and should not be closed as off-topic.

Comment: My bet is that he didn’t, based on his own comments in Mishnah Berurah 648:46 where he says that disqualifications that can only be seen by a magnifying glass don’t disqualify it.

Comment: I voted to close this as off topic because it is a question about a specific Jewish individual. The question gives no explanation for why the Chofetz Chaim specifically, saintly as he was, was chosen to be asked about, nor does it ask for his reasoning. It's a simple yes/no question that doesn't require any particular expertise in Judaism to answer

Comment: Many (if not all) Gdolim (גדולים) said that checking the Estrog with a magnifying glass is redundant. some said it's Bitul Torah (ביטול תורה).